# Richest strongest country fails

Tags: warfare, survival, super-powers

So say you have a country that is immensely wealthy. With a well educated population. Wealthier and smarter in a sense that money wasn't an issue and the country was the dominating super power of the world.... world War 3 happened.... how would the smaller enemy countries survive long enough to create a resistance and overall win.

-enemy countries can team up but still brings in below 50% of the wealth of the main country.

-goal is to win the hearts and minds and become the overall controlling body of the world. 
-guerilla warfare is encouraged for the weaker countries  but the wealthy country is not overall brutal. They do not kill civilians unless absolutely necessary.

How would the local population attack and want to attack and fight for sovereignty

Wealthy country wants overall control of  popumation of all enemy countries. Year is 2016

Comment: 1) You're asking us to write your story for you, which is off topic. 2) You're not providing nearly enough information. 3) 100% opinion based question. VTCing as such.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of different questions here.  How would the countries survive World War 3?  Assuming they survive, how would they fight back?   You need to narrow down to just one problem that is bothering you and concentrate the question on that.  As it is, this is quite open ended.

Comment: Horrible written question. I will work on recording and repost later everyone

Comment: Look at already fallen empires like the roman empire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wealth is not security

Education is not wisdom

Intelligence is not preparedness

Any idiot can be rich.  Being poor is a skill.

And there you have the cultural differences that will align your people.  You can fight sovereignty by just shrugging off their mechanisms of control.  Reject their technology, laws, and culture in favor of your own.

It also helps to have a charismatic leader who spouts better nonsense then the other guy.